# Trig identities - stuck solving $\tan^2\theta = -\frac 32 \sec\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation on the interval $0\leq \theta < 2\pi$

$$\tan^2 \theta = -\frac{3}{2}\sec \theta $$

Here are the steps I have so far:

**Identity: $\tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta -1 $**

Substitute:

$$\sec^2 \theta -1  = -\frac{3}{2}\sec \theta $$

$$2\sec^2 \theta -2 = {-3}\sec \theta $$

$$2\sec^2 \theta +3\sec \theta - 2 = 0 $$

Is this factoring correct?:

$$(2\sec\theta+4)(\sec\theta-1) = 0 $$

$$2\sec\theta+4 =0$$

$$2\sec\theta = -4 $$

$$\sec \theta = -2$$

$$(2\pi/3), (4\pi/3) $$

$$\sec\theta - 1 = 0$$

$$\sec\theta = 1 $$

$\sec\theta=1$ would evaluate to $0$, for some reason that is an invalid answer? (according to my assignment)

So is $\ (2\pi/3), (4\pi/3) $ the full answer?

Comment: Let $u = \sec \theta$ and work on factoring $2u^2 + 3u - 2$; you can always *multiply it out* to check that your factorization is correct (it's not right now). And you should always have *something* with trig functions (never $\sec$ alone, always $\sec \theta$, or whatever happens to be inside the trig functions).

Comment: write $(2\sec x-1)(\sec x+2) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the factoring is not correct - it should be $\left(2\sec\theta +4\right)\left(\sec\theta- \frac12\right)$

Comment: thank you. you mentioned something about periods and n? Do you mind elaborating. I would hate to miss something.

Comment: The solutions to e.g. $\sec \theta = -2$ are $\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi n$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi n$ for *each* integer value of $n$. I didn't notice at first that you're working in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, though, so it didn't matter here.

Answer (score 2):

Set $\cos\theta=t$; then
$$
\tan^2\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}
\qquad
\sec\theta=\frac{1}{t}
$$
and the equation becomes
$$
\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}=-\frac{3}{2t}
$$
that is,
$$
2-2t^2=-3t
$$
and finally
$$
2t^2-3t-2=0
$$
The roots are $2$ and $-1/2$. So the equation reduces to
$$
\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Why factor? It's fine, but in general when faced with something like

$$2\sec^2 \theta +3\sec \theta - 2 = 0$$

you could set $u=\sec\theta$ and then use the quadratic formula.

$$2u^2 +3u - 2 = 0$$

$$u = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{9-4(2)(-2)}}{2(2)} = \frac{-3 \pm 5}{4} = \frac12 , -2$$

Then solve for possible $\theta$ from $\sec\theta=1/2$ and $\sec\theta=-2$.